# Knockout.js and tables: Inserting <th> contents into matching <td>

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-table

I've created responsive tables like this:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

But I find the CSS-based adding of the content to be rather error-prone.

I am new to Knockout.js and I'd like to use it to insert the "key" of the `th` element into every one of my corresponding `td`'s like this:

```
 <td><span>[tr value]</span>[original td value]<td>
```

So basically I want to loop the th's into some array, and add them to a the same index inside each `tr`.

EDIT:

Here's what I managed to do: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxees2dk/3/)

Something wrong with the table rows and still missing the span's inside the td's which contain the key (header)

Comment: what exactly you trying to achieve here . As in the link above are you looking for alternate color to rows in datatable?

Comment: As you can see in the example, the table changes into a key-value pairs when screen is narrower. So i'd like to add those corresponding keys using KO instead of CSS's ":before"

Comment: well thats how it works . you have to try like this `<td> <span>Line</span> <span data-bind="text: line"></span></td>` . previously your `td` having data-bind replacing span with td's text . see here  http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/fxees2dk/6/ . cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data binding to the `tbody` not to `tr`

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: jobTitle"></td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fup93L5/)